# Why is my G5 running so slow and hot?

Tags: macos, mac, powerpc, power-mac

We have an early 2005 Power Macintosh G5 2.0 DP (PCI). This tower has been having a lot of problems: freezing randomly, runs hot and slow, fans race intermittently, CDs/DVDs don't always load, won't go to sleep sometimes...
What is happening and how can I fix this??

Here are additional specs:

Dual 2GHz PowerPC G5 Processor 
2GB DDR SDRAM 
Runs OS 10.5.8

This is the model info for this tower: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/powermac_g5/stats/powermac_g5_2.0_dp_pci.html

Additional System Profiler info is here at:
http://inventaweb.net/matthew/sysprofiler.txt

I deleted the log files from the file because they are way too long, but everything else is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be time to get a new Mac Pro. The processing units in these machines often don't last forever.

Otherwise, I would suggest backing up as many of your valuable files as you can, clearing your machine and reloading your OS from scratch (i.e. Install DVD).

Comment: Seconded. Also - if there is a repair shop nearby - ask what they would charge to run a sensor test / recalibrate the fan control to see if that helps. Sometimes as a G5 ages, the thermal calibration can need another run to adjust for added heat due to degrading components heating up more than when new.

Comment: Also - a fresh install of the OS might be good before spending any money on hardware. Especially if it's crashing and hasn't been reinstalled in the last year or so.

Comment: It's not the only computer we have, and it's not vital that it gets fixed. I am just trying to get it fixed if possible. All the files are backed up, so I'm fine there...Would the Apple Hardware Test work to recalibrate the system??

Comment: There is no thermal calibration for a Power Mac G5, don't pay someone to do this for you! The PMU works by measuring wattage (from 0-100W) to various components and increases the fan speed in proportionally with that.

Answer (score 1):

I recently downloaded the Free app Disk Drill for my G5, and one of its options is to use S.M.A.R.T. monitoring...long story short, along with a lot of other stuff, it keeps track of the temperature of my internal drives, and Man Alive! they are currently 116 and 98 degrees F. I put an external fan against it and the temp is slowly lowering.

I've heard from many sources that G5s are known for having heat dispersion problems, so, yeah, I'm glad you have alternate computers.   Good Luck!

Comment: Okay thanks...yeah this was a long time ago and we now have a MBP as the primary home computer. The G5 doesn't get used much anymore...